# Pass outer loop parameter to a Promise resolve

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, resolve

I have a for loop that queries a database. I want the db calls to be async.
This is the structure of the code:

```
for(var idx=0; idx<arr.rows.length; idx++)
{
  db.query(`SELECT ...`)
    .then((result) => {
          console.log("Value is: " + result.rows[idx].val);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I want the parameter `idx` printed in the resolve (`db.query` returns a Promise). But this way the wrong `idx` is printed because the `idx` value is incremented when the promise is resolved.

What is the proper way to pass the variable `idx`?
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good example of executing queries. You do not use a loop in JavaScript to execute several `SELECT` queries, it is very inefficient. And since your question got nothing to do with database queries at all, you should simplify the example to something more suitable and generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var`.

Change from this:

```
for(var idx=0; idx<arr.rows.length; idx++)
```

to this:

```
for(let idx=0; idx<arr.rows.length; idx++)
```

`let` is block-scoped to the block of the `for` loop and will maintain a separate copy of the variable for each iteration of the loop so that each one has its own and thus your asynchronous `.then()` handler that gets called after the `for` loop is completely done will still have the appropriate value in its own copy of `idx`.